# R, group by ID and sum columns by value in group without calling column names?

Tags: r

I've seen several answers on stackoverflow that do show how to use aggregate and summarize to get the sum of columns after grouping by a column. However, they all seem to rely on actually writing out the column names so I am having a hard time applying those solutions to my question.
Specifically, I need to minimize my dataframe so that it is grouped by ID, the temps (and other variables) are identical across the same ID so I need to keep those values the same, and sum up the columns for each species by the ID (I.e. add up their values).

```
df <- tibble(A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), temp=c(36.5,36.5,36.5,32,32,32), ID= c('a','a','a','b','b','b'), sp1=c(5,10,10,15,15,5), sp2=c(0,2,5,0,6,5), sp3=c(1,1,2,2,3,1))
```

I've tried versions of aggregate but they I don't know how to do it for many columns (I have 100s of species) and I don't know how to not merge the other variables like temperature.

```
aggregate(. ~ ID, df, sum)

   ID  A  temp sp1 sp2 sp3
1  a  6  109.5  25   7   4
2  b  15  96.0  35  11   6
```

Obviously not correct. My desired output is the following where I can even ignore a column like A which is just an extra value for the ID (but it's not important).

```
   ID  temp   sp1 sp2 sp3
1  a   36.5    25   7   4
2  b   32      35  11   6
```

I also tried:

```
aggregate(cbind(sp1,sp2,sp3) ~ ID, df, FUN=sum)

  ID sp1 sp2 sp3
1  a  25   7   4
2  b  35  11   6
```

which gets me closer but then I still don't know how to keep the temp column unchanged, and I don't know how to make it call for a large number of species. I have sometimes tables that go from sp1 to sp1000...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this get you what you want?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(-A) %>% 
  group_by(ID, temp) %>% # all "common to each group" vars
  summarise(across(everything(), sum), .groups = "drop")


# A tibble: 2 x 5
  ID     temp   sp1   sp2   sp3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a      36.5    25     7     4
2 b      32      35    11     6
```

Comment: Sorry took a while to respond - had to reinstall my R as I messed up some stuff. This worked thank you!